# passing types to initialState in slice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I did this dictionary project fine using Props.  Now I am trying to do in redux-toolkit.

I have types in a separate file

```
export type searchType = {
  word: string;
}

export type meaningsType = {
  word: string;
  phonetic: string;
  phonetics:[text: string, audio: string];
  meanings:[
    {
      partOfSpeech: string;
      definitions:[
        {
          definition: string;
          synonyms: string[];
          antonyms: string[];
        }
      ];
    }
  ];
  license: {
    name: string;
    url: string;
  };
  sourceUrls: string;
};
```

I import this into a dictionarySlice.ts file

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { searchType, meaningsType } from "../../types/dictionary";;

export type dictionaryState = {
  word: searchType;
  dictionary: meaningsType;
}

const initialState: dictionaryState  = {
  word: '',
  dictionary: [],
}

export const dictionarySlice = createSlice({
  name: 'dictionary',
  initialState,
  
  reducers: {
    
  }
})
```

How can I pass more than one type when creating initialState?  Because in my example for value of initialState of word complains with error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'searchType'.ts(2322)
> dictionarySlice.ts(5, 3): The expected type comes from property 'word' which is declared here on type 'dictionaryState'
> (property) word: searchType

Getting similar error for value of initialState of dictionary.  I cannot go further defining reducers until this error is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

You've typed `searchType` to be an object with a `word` property that is a string type.

```js
export type searchType = {
  word: string;
}
```

So by declaring the slice state `dictionaryState` type to have a word property that is type `searchType`

```js
export type dictionaryState = {
  word: searchType;
  dictionary: meaningsType;
}
```

It's expecting a value that is an object with a `word` property that is a string type, e.g.

```js
const initialState: dictionaryState  = {
  word: { word: '' },
  ...
}
```

You've additionally provided incorrect `state.dictionary` value as well. It is typed as `dictionary: meaningsType;` but the initial state is an array.

## Solution

I suspect you really do want `state.word` to be a string, and for `state.dictionary` to be an array of `meaningsType` objects.

```js
export type dictionaryState = {
  word: string;
  dictionary: meaningsType[];
}
```

The following may also work, basically *extending* the `searchType` to include the dictionary property (*be careful though if the `searchType` type changes*):

```js
export type dictionaryState = searchType & {
  dictionary: meaningsType[];
}
```

With this typing you'll be able to use the following `initialState` value:

```js
const initialState: dictionaryState  = {
  word: '',       // <-- string
  dictionary: [], // <-- meaningsType[]
}
```

Comment: So it is not possible to have the same thing defined in 2 didfferent type?  Word in searchType is what user enters to lookup meaning
 and word used in meaningsType, is what returns by API as part of response along with phonetic, phonetics, meanings....  Please advice, in future I'll call them different then.
Thanks,

Comment: @user3269443 You can have the same keys declared in different types, e.g. `searchType` type can have a `word` property/type, and `meaningsType` type can also have a `word` property/type, and these "word" properties can be the same, or different, types. They are independent. This wasn't really the issue you had in your code though.

Comment: @user3269443 Hopefully I understood your comment/question correctly. In the meantime, has an answer here helped address/resolve your question/issue?

Comment: Sorry, with balck Friday and ordering parts for a new PC build, I got side tracked.  Let me be clear and get a good understanding.  So in a separate file when I am exporting two different types, with one just a string, and another with object, the way
I constructed searchType type always create an abject.  So what is the proper syntax to create a type with just one string item?  If I am clear, then I'll be more than happy to give you the green mark.  Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: @user3269443 Can you clarify what you mean by "create a type with just one string item"? Do you mean a type with one property that is a string type, e.g. `type SomeType = { someStringProperty: string; }`? `SearchType` isn't an object, but it types an object, e.g. an object with a `word` property that is a string type. It works when specifying a React component's props because the `props` is an object.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I have my answer.  Wish best happy holiday to you and your family.

Answer (score 1):

Is `word` a string or an object with a `word` key whose type is a string?

```js
// searchType is an object with a `word` key
export type searchType = {
  word: string;
}

// word is type searchType (which is an object with a `word` key
export type dictionaryState = {
  word: searchType;
  dictionary: meaningsType;
}

const initialState: dictionaryState  = {
  word: '', // this is *wrong*, `word` looks like `{ word: string };`
  dictionary: [],
}
```

this would be a valid `initialState`:

```js
const initialState: dictionaryState  = {
  word: {
    word: '',
  },
  dictionary: [],
}
```

Comment: how can word in searchType be an object?  It is clearly defined as string type.   When I used it as Props in other project, I use string type all over the place with no issue!!!
-
And what about the value of initialState dictionary which is an object it also complains with 
"Type 'never[]' is missing the following properties from type 'meaningsType': word, phonetic, phonetics, meanings, and 2 more.ts(2740)
dictionarySlice.ts(6, 3): The expected type comes from property 'dictionary' which is declared here on type 'dictionaryState'
(property) dictionary: meaningsType"